# Найдите все 4х значные числа, сумма каждого из которых равна 15

Tags: c#

Найдите все 4х значные числа, сумма цифр каждого из которых равна 15.
Не могу понять, прошу о помощи

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, Вам необходимо узнать, равна ли сумма всех цифр числа пятнадцати. Если так, то ниже представлен один из способов.

```c
_Bool isFh(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        sum += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return sum == 15;
}

int main(void) {
    for (int i = 1000; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        if (isFh(i))
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```